# Controlling Page State With re-base or reactfire

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, reactfire

currently looking in to making a new web app with `Firebase`, `React` and `re-base` or `reactfire`. I understand that `Flux` when used with `Firebase` does not make complete sense, and they don't work well together. My question is, if I do not use `Flux` or `Redux`, but instead just `re-base` or `reactfire` how do I control the page's state? For instance, knowing a drop down is active.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, knowing a drop-down is active is perfectly managed by using React, without the use of redux or flux and regardless of what backend you are using.

For example (and I'm making some assumptions here what functionality you want precisely):

- Set your initial state to `{ ddActive: false }`
- Then `setState({ ddActive: true })` on clicking the dropdown button
- Then, on clicking anywhere, `setState({ ddActive: false })` again

Hope this helps!